# Excel conditional formatting based on repeated values

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I am using the following formula to color entire row where value in column A is greater than 20.

> =$A1>20
>   then formatting the entire row with range 
>   =$1:$65536

and get the following output

[image]

How could I modify the rule to highlight the rows only if value in column A is greater than 20 for more than 2 consecutive rows to get the following output.

[image]

Comment: `is repeated more than 2 times` - can you clarify please? in the image above I don't see that 24,25,30 somehow repeated

Comment: Sorry I was not clear, I mean if value in column A is greater than 20 for more than two consecutive rows - then highlight. I'll edit the question as well

Comment: as I see, it should be sth like this: 1) first CF for fisrt row: `=AND($A1>20,$A2>20)`. 2) for second and below rows CF: `=AND($A2>20,OR($A1>20,$A3>20))`

Answer (score 0):

Add a couple of rows at the top, select entire ColumnA and other columns to suit and a CF formula rule of:

```
=XOR(AND($A1048575>20,$A1048576>20,$A1>20),AND($A1048576>20,$A1>20,$A2>20),AND($A1>20,$A2>20,$A3>20))
```

should suit, for Excel 2013.